# What does "on MB" mean in the context of laptop memory?

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard

I'm looking at [Lenovo laptops](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/x-series/x1-carbon/), and the two memory options for one machine are "8GB PC3-12800 DDR3L on MB" and "16GB PC3-12800 DDR3L on MB". What does "on MB" mean in this context? Does this mean "on motherboard" and mean that the memory is embedded in the motherboard (and therefore more difficult or impossible to upgrade by buying laptop RAM sticks separately)?

Comment: I think it means "on motherboard" - meaning it's soldered on and you can't replace or upgrade it easily.

Comment: Memory chips soldered onto the motherboard would reduce cost and weight, and use less volume (i.e. thinner case).

Comment: @LawrenceC is right. It's soldered on to the motherboard. You can [verify that here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/upgrading-ram-ssd-on-x1-carbon/m-p/827983#M42392).

Comment: @LawrenceC Ok, thanks. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it. It's also unfortunate that the SSD isn't a standard 2.5" form factor, so I wouldn't simply be able to update it with a larger, off-the-shelf drive (e.g. the older SATA hard drives I have laying around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Yes, it means it's built into the motherboard so you can't upgrade it!

Comment: “By the way, there is some technician who has the tool to still change those type of things.” No, not really. You’d need to remove BGA chips and then put in new ones. You can see an image [on this page](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Update-Lenovo-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Ultrabook.85315.0.html#toc-connectivity), just a little futher down.

Comment: Back in my technician days they were another configuration between those two here, but I don't want the post to be misunderstood thanks @DanielB

Comment: @DanielB Yes, really. It's possible to do such work in the field. Look at Louis Rossman's videos on YouTube. Difficult, and it requires a rework station that costs around $7000, but it can be done.